# Typesetting dense list of names for credits

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, typography

I am trying to make a list of names look decent for a credits section.

My approach is to fit as many names as possible on a line, without allowing breaks in the name, and separating each name by a bullet (see end of post for example).

One thing I don't like about the solution is the bullets that appear at the end of the lines. The one at the very end is easy to workaround, but I'm not sure how to deal with the others. Is there a good way to suppress those while keeping the intermediate ones?

Also, is there a way I can guarantee the spacing around an individual bullet is equal (so it is centered in between two names)? I could hardcode the space, but then I'm limiting the engine for spacing things out nicely.

Or am I going about this whole thing wrong, and there is there a much better way of typesetting this.

#### MWE

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\credit}[1]{\mbox{#1} $\bullet$}

\begin{document}

% Bunch of fake names
\begin{center}
\credit{Torri Askew}
\credit{Chelsea Coffey}
\credit{Charissa Lapeyrouse}
\credit{Griselda P. Macbeth}
\credit{Ria Segawa}
\credit{Katelin Leitzel}
\credit{L. J. Debow}
\credit{Valda Swofford}
\credit{Katherin D. Demayo}
\credit{Yael Kivi}
\credit{Filomena Tallmadge}
\credit{Max Mattia}
\credit{Jean-Kary Tiner}
\credit{Efren Caley}
\credit{Doria Ripley}
\credit{Edith I. Mccauley}
\credit{Carlyn Cundiff}
\credit{Gianna Gadison}
\credit{Magali Mosteller}
\credit{Charmain Mehan}
\credit{Arlena Merrigan}
\credit{Jordan Eich}
\credit{Bella Paton}
\credit{Roxane Wyse}
\credit{Maragaret Oakland}
\credit{Shakia Micek}
\credit{Erlene Chilcott}
\credit{Jolyn Castille}
\credit{Dirk Glavin}
\credit{Adah Aikins}
\credit{Jamila Brannum}
\credit{Jeramy Faulkenberry}
\credit{Roselyn Hilaire}
\credit{Lucila Marek}
\credit{Kristal Berkley}
\credit{Joey Fetterolf}
\credit{Alexandria Lagace}
\credit{Sharice Mckelvy}
\credit{Elise Scipio}
\credit{Kraig Demasi}
\credit{Brock Oh}
\credit{Refugia Brunke}
\credit{Eun Hulen}
\credit{Fatimah Groesbeck}
\credit{Noella Corley}
\credit{Florance Anthony}
\credit{Monroe Okelley}
\credit{Pearly Franko}
\credit{Venetta Steck}
\credit{Lieselotte Detty}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Centered names]

Comment: the spacing around the bullets is already equal, personally I think they far too big and distracting and I'd use `,` rather than ` * `, you could suppress the ones at the end of the lines but it seems a bit unnatural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd just use simple commas as in 2nd example, or perhaps the 4th with `\cdot` but some possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}



\begin{document}
\vspace*{-4cm}

% Bunch of fake names
\def\zzz{\begin{center}
\credit{Torri Askew}
\credit{Chelsea Coffey}
\credit{Charissa Lapeyrouse}
\credit{Griselda P. Macbeth}
\credit{Ria Segawa}
\credit{Katelin Leitzel}
\credit{L. J. Debow}
\credit{Valda Swofford}
\credit{Katherin D. Demayo}
\credit{Yael Kivi}
\credit{Filomena Tallmadge}
\credit{Max Mattia}
\credit{Jean-Kary Tiner}
\credit{Efren Caley}
\credit{Doria Ripley}
\credit{Edith I. Mccauley}
\credit{Carlyn Cundiff}
\credit{Gianna Gadison}
\credit{Magali Mosteller}
\credit{Charmain Mehan}
\credit{Arlena Merrigan}
\credit{Jordan Eich}
\credit{Bella Paton}
\credit{Roxane Wyse}
\credit{Maragaret Oakland}
\credit{Shakia Micek}
\credit{Erlene Chilcott}
\credit{Jolyn Castille}
\credit{Dirk Glavin}
\credit{Adah Aikins}
\credit{Jamila Brannum}
\credit{Jeramy Faulkenberry}
\credit{Roselyn Hilaire}
\credit{Lucila Marek}
\credit{Kristal Berkley}
\credit{Joey Fetterolf}
\credit{Alexandria Lagace}
\credit{Sharice Mckelvy}
\credit{Elise Scipio}
\credit{Kraig Demasi}
\credit{Brock Oh}
\credit{Refugia Brunke}
\credit{Eun Hulen}
\credit{Fatimah Groesbeck}
\credit{Noella Corley}
\credit{Florance Anthony}
\credit{Monroe Okelley}
\credit{Pearly Franko}
\credit{Venetta Steck}
\credit{Lieselotte Detty}
\end{center}}


\newcommand{\credit}[1]{\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\space\textbullet\space\fi\mbox{#1}}
\zzz

\renewcommand{\credit}[1]{\ifhmode\unskip, \space\fi\mbox{#1}}
\zzz


\newbox\zzzbox
\sbox\zzzbox{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\credit}[1]{\ifhmode\unskip\space\cleaders\copy\zzzbox\hskip\wd\zzzbox\relax\space\fi\mbox{#1}}
\zzz


\newbox\zzzbox
\sbox\zzzbox{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\credit}[1]{\ifhmode\unskip\space\cleaders\copy\zzzbox\hskip\wd\zzzbox\relax\space\fi\mbox{#1}}
\zzz


\end{document}
```